# When should I use VMware V-sphere, when should I use workstation?

Tags: virtualization, vmware, vmware-workstation, dualboot

I have read multiple answers related to cases where people wondered whether to dual boot or make VMs. I kind of gotten a sense that VMing is more appreciated than to dual boot, the disadvantages of which I understood. But I still don't get when to use a bare metal hypervisor and when to use a type 2. Could anybody please explain?.. I am new to this topic. Also, if I opted to use Vsphere and VMed windows, can I run a performance heavy app or a game from a remote desktop?

Comment: VMware ESX bare metal hypervisor is normally used for servers and used in this way is better performance than Workstation on a Server. You would need to do some research before committing a workstation to ESX.  VMware Workstation on a fast workstation with fast SSD drive handles most virtual loads very well.  Games need enhanced Video and are not suited to VMware Workstation (for sure) or ESX (so far as I know).

Comment: @John Do you say there's no way to run such games on virtualized servers at all?.. I mean dual booting doesn't seem practical for just one application even if it is performance heavy right?..

Comment: Simple minded games should work fine. But action games that use direct calls to the video card are not going to work in a virtual machine because the VM does not have direct access to the video hardware. My own ThinkPad does not even have a host video for games.

Comment: VMWare vSphere isn't actually a Hypervisor.  It simply manages an ESXi host.  vSphere is useless without a VMWare ESXi host. What GPUs are support by ESXi are pretty specific. ESXi supports GPU passthrough so running high performance applications shouldn't be a problem provided you have a supported GPU.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh my bad. I actually thought it is called "VMware vSphere ESXI". Didn't know vSphere is to manage ESXi host. Thanks for the clarification!. So do you say there wont be latency issues with accessing video card and other hardware as mentioned by @John?

Comment: @manojkumar - Disregard what I have said with regards to the name, I was having a brain fart, ESXi does support GPU passthrough but it's a Linux OS.  You lose the entire bare metal computer and it can be used for nothing other than running VMs.  vSphere is an umbrella term that includes several different products.

Comment: SO first of all, it's ESXi (vSphere is a management platform) which is a hypervisor. It runs directly on the hardware while Workstation works on top of an OS. Therefore, since ESXi runs natively on the hardware, it has direct access to resources which usually also translates into better performance. Everything depends on your use case. If you are looking for a server or moreover a cluster, then ESXi. If that's for one or two simple VMs and you have just a single PC for that, then Workstation.